# How to pass resources from parent to child stack in nested cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

My nested stack requires resources located in my main stack. eg: A lambda function in the nested stack requiring DB configs

```
   "ProjectsusgetProjectFinancialsLF": {
            "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
            "Properties": {
                "Code": {
                    "S3Bucket": "dev",
                    "S3Key": "test-lamda.zip",
                    "S3ObjectVersion": "9eNYbcI5EOuuut9igX2xpgbGCtKD1D4K"
                },
                "Environment": {
                    "Variables": {
                        "MYSQLDB_USER": {
                            "Ref": "DBuser"
                        },
                        "MYSQLDB_HOST": {
                            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                "testDB",
                                "Endpoint.Address"
                            ]
                        },
                        "MYSQLDB_DATABASE": {
                            "Ref": "DBname"
                        },
                        "MYSQLDB_PASSWORD": {
                            "Ref": "DBpass"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "Description": "A get project financials function",
                "FunctionName": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        "-",
                        [
                            {
                                "Ref": "EnvType"
                            },
                            "getProjectFinancials"
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                "Handler": "src/controllers/projects.geFinancials",
                "Role": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "LambdaExecutionRole",
                        "Arn"
                    ]
                },
                "Runtime": "nodejs6.10"
            },
            "DependsOn": [
                "LambdaExecutionRole"
            ]
        },
```

So I am passing the required params from my main stack to the nested using parameters :

```
"FinancialStack": {
    "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
    "Properties": {
        "TemplateURL": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/dev/child-cft.json",
        "TimeoutInMinutes": "5",
        "Parameters": {
            "DBuser": {
                "Ref": "DBuser",
                "Type": "String"
            },
            "epmoliteDB": {
                "Ref": "testDB",
                "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance"
            },
            "DBname": {
                "Ref": "DBname",
                "Type": "String"
            },
            "DBPass": {
                "Ref": "DBpass",
                "Type": "String"
            },
            "EnvType": {
                "Ref": "EnvType",
                "Type": "String"
            },
            "LambdaExecutionRole": {
                "Ref": "LambdaExecutionRole",
                "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role"
            },
            "ApiGatewayRestApi": {
                "Ref": "ApiGatewayRestApi",
                "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I am receiving them in my nested stack :

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "AWS CloudFormation to generate testone shot deployment",
    "Parameters": {
        "DBuser": {
            "Ref": "DBuser",
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "epmoliteDB": {
            "Ref": "testDB",
            "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance"
        },
        "DBname": {
            "Ref": "DBname",
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "DBPass": {
            "Ref": "DBpass",
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "EnvType": {
            "Ref": "EnvType",
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "LambdaExecutionRole": {
            "Ref": "LambdaExecutionRole",
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role"
        },
        "ApiGatewayRestApi": {
            "Ref": "ApiGatewayRestApi",
            "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
        }
    },
```

Yet when I run the cloudformation script it fails to create the nested stack. Am I passing the resources incorrectly from my main stack to the nested stack?

Should I instead export the parameters in the output of the main stack and import them in my nested stack using "Fn:ImportValue" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many things preventing these templates to work.

Let's start with the nested stack template. You can't to use the `"Ref"` intrinsic function inside the input parameters. Just the type is enough. Also not everything is supported as parameter type ([here's the list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types)), for exemple, `"Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"` is not a valid parameter type. When something is not directly supported, just use the `"String"` type. In fact, for nested stacks you can make your life easier and just use the `"String"` type.

Next thing to fix is the `AWS::CloudFormation::Stack` resource block. Here you used the `"Type"` properties to for each passed `"Parameters"` but you actually can't specify the type there. It's the job of the nested template to dictate which type of input it's expecting.

I highly recommend you to take the time to read the [CloudFormation documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html). Even better, read some examples made by AWS. [Here's a good example of nested stacks](https://github.com/aws-samples/ecs-refarch-cloudformation), just have a look at master.yaml.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up using "String" everywhere. The example mostly talks about passing resources from one nested stack to another. Whereas I want to pass resources from parent to child, so I can't use output .